# Is encoding of a character depends on Font-style of typography

Tags: encoding

Please help,
I learned that our modern computers save data only in sequences of bits (ie. either 0 or 1) and display output depending on that convention byte.
so, if I have char 'Z' which is binded to number 90 in ASCII standard and byte form as '0b1011010'. Then if my computer wants to display 'Z' in other font-family, so it uses '0b1011010' or something other binary form.
Hope you understand what I want's to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends.

You have a file with a `Z`. If you read the file binary, this will have the value `0x5A` (on most modern system, with default settings).

But this just mean the letter `Z`, nothing more.

If you want to include font information, you must use some proper document format. Maybe with `**Z**` you may get a bold Z (e.g. in this site). Or your may specify `<font face=....>Z</font>`. Or maybe with TeX/LaTeX, or other means.

Computers do not know the meaning of `0x5A`. On a graphical interface, a program will read your formatted file, and ask the graphical interface to draw a Z with a specific font. The GUI will look for font in the system, and design the letter Z according the rules (it may be just an image to be scaled, or a list of strokes, or more complex rules). The resulting bitmap is then send to video card, as pixels that should be shown with the correct colour (foreground/background).

There is really a lot of step, many are very complex. And there are many special cases. Windows as example may use internally UTF-16 and so not just `0x5A` for Z, but two bytes (e.g. `0x5A 0x00`, not sure about endianess).

Note: usually we do not refer the inclusion of font data as "encoding", but just as formatting language (also because it is not strictly an encoding). Unicode explicitly tell us that formatting and font information should not be encoded as character code, but on a level above.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for sharing such kind of great stuff.